# How to test V-BTN inside V-MENU?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vuetify.js

I'm trying to write test for my component and in this component i have a `<V-MENU>` and when it's activated, I'll get a form inside that component and in this form there's a `<V-BTN>`. so i managed to reach to buttons or items outside this menu but when i try to find my button inside menu, test will fail.

Basic Vue Component :

```
<v-btn
    data-testid="working-button"
    @click="workingbutton()"
    >
               Working Button
</v-btn>
<v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    data-testid="isMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :nudge-width="200"
    offset-x
>
     <v-btn
         data-testid="btn-one"
         @click="doSomething"
        >
               BTN 1
    </v-btn>

    <v-card data-testid="card-test">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="country"
            outlined
            label="Email"/>

        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn
                data-testid="btn-two"
                @click="doSomething"
            >
                {{ login ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

Test Unit :

```
const wrapper = mount(TestComponent, {
    store,
    localVue,
    vuetify
})

// Passed
expect(wrapper.vm.menu).toBe(false);
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="working-button"]').exists()).toBe(true);
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="isMenu"]').exists()).toBe(true);
const menuButton = wrapper.find('[data-testid="working-button"]')
menuButton.vm.$emit('click')
expect(wrapper.vm.menu).toBe(true);

// Will Fail
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="btn-one"]').exists()).toBe(true);

// Will Fail
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="card-test"]').exists()).toBe(true);

// Will Fail
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="btn-two"]').exists()).toBe(true);
```

Above codes are a basic example which I've tried to make it short in order to don't waste your time in reading it.
So as you can see in top I've triggered `Working button` to set menu to true, then tried to find the button, and the reason that I've did this was that, i thought maybe menu should be true, but it wasn't and it's still fail.

Answer (score 1):

Like most components that create popups or overlays, the content of Vuetify's `v-menu` isn't rendered within the component itself, but at the point specified in [its `attach` property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-attach), by default the root of your Vue app.

You will have to look outside your `wrapper` for the rendered menu. This should do it, assuming you have `createWrapper` imported from `vue-test-utils`:

```js
const menu = createWrapper(document.body).find('.v-menu__content');
```

(You could also pass the specific element that is your app root instead of `document.body` to be more precise.) Then you would look for everything *within* the menu on the `menu` wrapper instead of the `wrapper` wrapper.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answer. I'm sorry but I'm not really pro in testing. so as you said I've tried to import `DOMWrapper` from `vue-test-utils => like this => import { mount, createLocalVue, DOMWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'`, but it's failing with this error `  _testUtils.DOMWrapper is not a constructor`...

Comment: @Atlas-Pio Oops, I've been using vue-test-utils 2 (for Vue 3) and put in its API. I've edited my answer to use the v1 API instead.

Comment: Well, I've tried this, but failed again. maybe because I'm still in a wonderland. can you please use my example to show me how it's done?
As i said, i can find v-menu in test(in above example, v-menu data test exist is true, but i can't reach to buttons or elements/components in v-menu.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio Ah, sorry, it looks like Vuetify structures this a little differently than other frameworks I've seen. I've edited my answer again to include the correct selector for the part that is rendered outside of the app root. This would go right above your `const menuButton = ...` line, which would then become `... = menu.find('[data-testid="working-button"]')`.